# Changing class name and changing event response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a button with the class `add-to-favorite` when clicked the class is changed to `remove-from-favorite` and a file is added to favorite. When the user clicks on the button again, it has `remove-from-favorite` The class is changed to `add-to-favorite` and the file must be removed from the favorite, but this is not the case. The button acts like the `remove-from-favorite` even if the class is `add-to-favorite;`. Any ideas?

Here is the code :

```
<button type="button" class="add-to-favorite" name="button"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></button>
```

Here is the Javascript code for `add-to-favorite`

```
$(".add-to-favorite").on("click", function(event) {
var clicked_button = $(this); 
    clicked_button.html("<i class='material-icons'>close</i>");
    clicked_button.removeClass('add-to-favorite');
    clicked_button.addClass('remove-from-favorite');
 })
```

Here is javascript for `remove-from-favorite`

```
$(".remove-from-favorite").on("click", function(event) {
var clicked_button = $(this);
    clicked_button.html("<i class='material-icons'>favorite_border</i>");
    clicked_button.removeClass('remove-from-favorite');
    clicked_button.addClass('add-to-favorite');
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use $(document).on() for click event:

```
$(document).on("click",".add-to-favorite", function(event) {
    var clicked_button = $(this); 
        clicked_button.html("<i class='material-icons'>close</i>");
        clicked_button.removeClass('add-to-favorite');
        clicked_button.addClass('remove-from-favorite');
 });

 $(document).on("click",".remove-from-favorite", function(event) {
    var clicked_button = $(this);
        clicked_button.html("<i class='material-icons'>favorite_border</i>");
        clicked_button.removeClass('remove-from-favorite');
        clicked_button.addClass('add-to-favorite');
 });
```

Comment: thank you, that solved the problem; please would you tell me why $(document)... has worked and the other way has not ?

Comment: because for dynamically added/updated element we need to use document.on()  only